# How to extract value from Html.Attribute in Elm

Tags: elm

I have a problem when I want to read Html.Attribute in Elm language.
I want to make a custom tag like below;

```
myTag : List ( Html.Attribute msg ) -> List ( Html msg ) -> Html msg
myTag attributes children = 
    -- case attributes has "src" show button with image
    -- otherwise show normal button
```

so when I call myTag, if I specific src, I will get button with image automatically, such as;

```
myTag [ src="somepic.jpg" ][]  -- show a button with image
```

Or

```
myTag [][]                     -- show a normal button
```

I tried to debug to see what is inside "Html.Attribute". It contains something like `( a2 "<tag-name>" <tag-value> )`  or `( a3 "<tag-name>" <tag-value> )`. However, I do not know how to extract `"<tag-name>"`, which I think it is a String from those values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Html.Attribute`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html#Attribute) type is opaque. There is no information you can pull out of it for use inside an Elm application, because the package offers no way to extract data or inspect an `Attribute` value from within Elm code.

Yes, you *can* use a javascript debugger to look at how Elm code compiles down to Javascript, but this won't help much in deconstructing the `Attribute` type from within Elm code.

If you want to inspect attributes, I'd recommend using a `Dict String String` as your attributes parameter instead:

```
myTag : Dict String String -> List ( Html msg ) -> Html msg
```

Comment: are there any particular reasons that Elm need to hide Html.Attribute instead of freely extracting value?

Comment: It's not exposed because it's a data structure that is used internally in the virtual-dom package. Exposing the internal structure would make it harder to make changes to that package without breaking external code.

It's always best to keep internal implementation details private unless there is a good reason to make them public.